# How to generate random 64-bit unsigned integer in C

Tags: c, random, unsigned-integer

I need generate random 64-bit unsigned integers using C. I mean, the range should be `0` to `18446744073709551615`. `RAND_MAX` is `1073741823`.

I found some solutions in the links which might be possible duplicates but the answers mostly concatenates some `rand()` results or making some incremental arithmetic operations. So results are always 18 digits or 20 digits. I also want outcomes like `5`, `11`, `33387`, not just `3771778641802345472`.

By the way, I really don't have so much experience with the C but any approach, code samples and idea could be beneficial.

Comment: **Don't** concatenate `rand()` as you'll have all sorts of autocorrelation effects, and the distribution will not be uniform. Take a look at these: http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/VERSIONS/C-LANG/c-lang.html

Comment: `I also want outcomes like 5, 11, 33387` => there is 10 times more number between 1000000000000000000 and 9999999999999999999 than between 0 and 1000000000000000000... so don't expect to see numbers like 5 soon

Comment: You seem to be confused about base-10 digits (0...9), and bits (base-2 digits). Keep these separate in your thinking, for better understanding.

Comment: the probability you get 5 is just like the probability you get 3771778641802345472, which is equal to 1/2^64, a very very small number. So simply concatenating the bits works, unless you have some more strict requirements

Comment: @Bathsheba I looked that page. Most of the links are broken. It looks outdated but I got the idea you wanted to give. Thomas You are so right, but as Lưu Vĩnh Phúc said I just want equal possibilities for both 5 and 3771778641802345472. And hyde You may right. I will try to edit something for better understanding.

Comment: Check this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20175148/64bit-random-number-between-a-range

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate a random number in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822323/how-to-generate-a-random-number-in-c)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting big random numbers in C/C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28115724/getting-big-random-numbers-in-c-c)

Comment: @nwellnhof A problem with that duplicate is that the best answer for C and C++ can differ.  The accepted answer is a C one - for now -- but that post should have focused on 1 language, like this post.

Comment: @Erdi İzgi Suggest reviewing these answers, up-voting useful ones and accepting one.  Might want to do that with many of your other questions too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Concerning "So results are always 18 digits or 20 digits."

See [@Thomas comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33010010/how-to-generate-random-64-bit-unsigned-integer-in-c/33021408#comment53843951_33010010).  If you generate random numbers long enough, code will create ones like 5, 11 and 33387.  If code generates 1,000,000,000 numbers/second, it may take a year as very small numbers < 100,000 are so rare amongst all 64-bit numbers.

---

`rand()` simple returns random bits.  A simplistic method pulls 1 bit at a time

```
uint64_t rand_uint64_slow(void) {
  uint64_t r = 0;
  for (int i=0; i<64; i++) {
    r = r*2 + rand()%2;
  }
  return r;
}
```

---

Assuming `RAND_MAX` is some power of 2 - 1 as in OP's case `1073741823 == 0x3FFFFFFF`, take advantage that <strike>30</strike> *at least 15* bits are generated each time.  The following code will call `rand()` 5 <strike>3</strike> times - a tad wasteful.  Instead bits shifted out could be saved for the next random number, but that brings in other issues.  Leave that for another day.

```
uint64_t rand_uint64(void) {
  uint64_t r = 0;
  for (int i=0; i<64; i += 15 /*30*/) {
    r = r*((uint64_t)RAND_MAX + 1) + rand();
  }
  return r;
}
```

A portable loop count method avoids the `15 /*30*/` - **But see 2020 edit below**.

```
#if RAND_MAX/256 >= 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
  #define LOOP_COUNT 1
#elif RAND_MAX/256 >= 0xFFFFFF
  #define LOOP_COUNT 2
#elif RAND_MAX/256 >= 0x3FFFF
  #define LOOP_COUNT 3
#elif RAND_MAX/256 >= 0x1FF
  #define LOOP_COUNT 4
#else
  #define LOOP_COUNT 5
#endif

uint64_t rand_uint64(void) {
  uint64_t r = 0;
  for (int i=LOOP_COUNT; i > 0; i--) {
    r = r*(RAND_MAX + (uint64_t)1) + rand();
  }
  return r;
}
```

The autocorrelation effects commented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33010010/how-to-generate-random-64-bit-unsigned-integer-in-c/33021408#comment53843879_33010010) are caused by a weak `rand()`.  C does not specify a particular method of random number generation.  The above relies on `rand()` - or whatever base random function employed - being good.

If `rand()` is sub-par, then code should use other generators. Yet one can still use this approach to build up larger random numbers.

---

[Edit 2020]

[Hallvard B. Furuseth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4589384/2410359) provides as nice way to determine the number of bits in `RAND_MAX` when it is a [Mersenne Number](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MersenneNumber.html) - a power of 2 minus 1.

```
#define IMAX_BITS(m) ((m)/((m)%255+1) / 255%255*8 + 7-86/((m)%255+12))
#define RAND_MAX_WIDTH IMAX_BITS(RAND_MAX)
_Static_assert((RAND_MAX & (RAND_MAX + 1u)) == 0, "RAND_MAX not a Mersenne number");

uint64_t rand64(void) {
  uint64_t r = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 64; i += RAND_MAX_WIDTH) {
    r <<= RAND_MAX_WIDTH;
    r ^= (unsigned) rand();
  }
  return r;
}
```

Comment: This answer is like a poem. I mean the explanations. I totally understood everything related with my question.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't need cryptographically secure pseudo random numbers, I would suggest using MT19937-64. It is a 64 bit version of [Mersenne Twister PRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister).

Please, do not combine `rand()` outputs and do not build upon other tricks. Use existing implementation:

http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/emt64.html

Answer (score 2):

Iff you have a sufficiently good source of random bytes (like, say, /dev/random or /dev/urandom on a linux machine), you can simply consume 8 bytes from that source and concatenate them. If they are independent and have a linear distribution, you're set.

If you don't, you MAY get away by doing the same, but there is likely to be some artefacts in your pseudo-random generator that gives a toe-hold for all sorts of hi-jinx.

Example code assuming we have an open binary `FILE *source`:

```
/* Implementation #1, slightly more elegant than looping yourself */
uint64_t 64bitrandom() 
{
  uint64_t rv;
  size_t count;

  do {
   count = fread(&rv, sizeof(rv), 1, source);
  } while (count != 1);
  return rv;
}

/* Implementation #2 */
uint64_t 64bitrandom()
{
  uint64_t rv = 0;
  int c;

  for (i=0; i < sizeof(rv); i++) {
     do {
       c = fgetc(source)
     } while (c < 0);
     rv = (rv << 8) | (c & 0xff);
  }
  return rv;
}
```

If you replace "read random bytes from a randomness device" with "get bytes from a function call", all you have to do is to adjust the shifts in method #2.

You're vastly more likely to get a "number with many digits" than one with "small number of digits" (of all the numbers between 0 and 2 ** 64, roughly 95% have 19 or more decimal digits, so really that is what you will mostly get.

Comment: What is "hi-jinx"? =)

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to use a repetitive pseudo random sequence and you can deal with a bunch of values that will never happen (like even numbers? ... don't use just the low bits), an LCG or MCG are simple solutions.  [Wikipedia: Linear congruential generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) can get you started (there are several more types including the commonly used [Wikipedia: Mersenne Twister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister)).  And [this site](https://asecuritysite.com/encryption/random3?val=64) can generate a couple prime numbers for the modulus and the multiplier below.  (caveat: this sequence will be guessable and thus it is *NOT* secure)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint64_t
mcg64(void)
{
    static uint64_t i = 1;
    return (i = (164603309694725029ull * i) % 14738995463583502973ull);
}

int
main(int ac, char * av[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        printf("%016p\n", mcg64());
}
```

Comment: Note: the `ll` are not needed in the 2 constants.  Better to use `"%016" PRIx64 "\n"` than `"%016p\n"` - insures a matching print specifier with `uint64_t`.  (See `<inttypes.h>`)

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this code [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php) and it seems to work fine there.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
  srand(time(NULL));
  int a = rand();
  int b = rand();
  int c = rand();
  int d = rand();
  long e = (long)a*b;
  e = abs(e);
  long f = (long)c*d;
  f = abs(f);

  long long answer = (long long)e*f;

  printf("value %lld",answer);
  return 0;
}
```

I ran a few iterations and i get the following outputs :

value 1869044101095834648
value 2104046041914393000

value 1587782446298476296
value 604955295827516250
value 41152208336759610
value 57792837533816000

Comment: Building up values with `*` as in `a*b` ruins the distribution of values generated.  `(long)a*b` and `abs(e)` can both incur signed integer overflow - which is _undefined behavior_ (UB).  `abs()` returns an `int`.  Using `abs(some_long)` creates additional concerns when `int/long` range differ.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 32 or 16-bit random value - generate 2 or 4 randoms and combine them to one 64-bit with `<<` and `|`.

```
uint64_t rand_uint64(void) {
    // Assuming RAND_MAX is 2^31.
    uint64_t r = rand();
    r = r<<30 | rand();
    r = r<<30 | rand();
    return r;
}
```

Comment: the thing is the OP's random value has only 30 bits

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted.  `uint64_t r = rand(); r = r<<30 | rand(); r = r<<30 | rand();` makes sense, if you know the value of `RAND_MAX` ahead of time.  Wish I could push this up several answers.

Comment: @ESV The answer in flawed in the comment `// Assuming RAND_MAX is 2^31.`  The answer makes sense if `RAND_MAX is 2^30 - 1`, as OP said. (i486 has wrong power-of-2, off-by-1).  It could be even better with `r = r<<30 ^ rand();`  (`^` vs `|`) as that would make sense for `RAND_MAX is 2^N - 1, N >= 30`, not just `N==30`.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

unsigned long long int randomize(unsigned long long int uint_64);

int main(void)
{
    srand(time(0));

    unsigned long long int random_number = randomize(18446744073709551615);

    printf("%llu\n",random_number);

    random_number = randomize(123);

    printf("%llu\n",random_number);

    return 0;

}

unsigned long long int randomize(unsigned long long int uint_64)
{
    char buffer[100] , data[100] , tmp[2];

    //convert llu to string,store in buffer
    sprintf(buffer, "%llu", uint_64);

    //store buffer length
    size_t len = strlen(buffer);

    //x : store converted char to int, rand_num : random number , index of data array
    int x , rand_num , index = 0;

    //condition that prevents the program from generating number that is bigger input value
    bool Condition = 0;

    //iterate over buffer array
    for( int n = 0 ; n < len ; n++ )
    {
        //store the first character of buffer
        tmp[0] = buffer[n];
        tmp[1] = '\0';

        //convert it to integer,store in x
        x = atoi(tmp);


        if( n == 0 )
        {
            //if first iteration,rand_num must be less than or equal to x
            rand_num = rand() % ( x + 1 );

            //if generated random number does not equal to x,condition is true
            if( rand_num != x )
                Condition = 1;

            //convert character that corrosponds to integer to integer and store it in data array;increment index
            data[index] = rand_num + '0';
            index++;
        }
        //if not first iteration,do the following
        else
        {
            if( Condition )
            {
                rand_num = rand() % ( 10 );

                data[index] = rand_num + '0';

                index++;
            }
            else
            {
                rand_num = rand() % ( x + 1 );

                if( rand_num != x )
                    Condition = 1;

                data[index] = rand_num + '0';

                index++;
            }
        }
    }

    data[index] = '\0';

    char *ptr ;

    //convert the data array to unsigned long long int
    unsigned long long int ret = _strtoui64(data,&ptr,10);

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: How does that satisfy the requirement for a random 64 bit unsigned int ?

Comment: Well, I tried your code and printed out 1000 outcome. Results are like this; 04951651604868241121, 00651604895168241121, 03943165433604438241, 00160434265465541121... so I guess we can't have what I need with this method.

Comment: you mean,you don't want the leading zeros ?

Comment: leading zeros is also but, with this solution it is almost impossible to have a result like 00000000000000345432

Comment: i guess rand() isn't that flexible